# Custom community displays error page “URL no longer exist”

Tags: community, force.com-sites, custom-domain

I have created a community with URL `https://abc-developer-edition.ap5.force.com` and is in active status. But the URL `https://mcdcommunity-developer-edition.ap5.force.com/s/` is showing as `URL No Longer Exists`.

When I go to `Administration-->Pages-->Go to Force.com`, It displays a site page with site label `abc`.

But when I go to `Setup-->Sites`, I see below image. Does the site gets automatically created with community and why does it not appear when I go from `setup`?

[image]

Comment: Isn’t your domain name set up with “abc” and that you are trying to access it with “mdcommunity”?

Comment: I have not created domain before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL `https://mcdcommunity-developer-edition.ap5.force.com/s/` is not valid until community is published. Making community `Active` is not enough. And Also until you create any domain name, `mcdcommunity` site will not be available through `Setup-->Sites` even though site with the same name gets created.